# Extending Visual Studio 2012 HTML IntelliSense

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I've got an interest in extending the HTML editor in Visual Studio 2012 to support some additional elements and attributes, beyond those supplied as part of the HTML5 specification.

For example:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Header Text</h1>
        <mycustomelement>some info</mycustomelement>
    </body>
</html>
```

I saw Mads Kristensen's excellent post, *[Custom schemas in VS2012 CSS editor](http://madskristensen.net/post/custom-schemas-in-vs2012-css-editor)*, that shows how to do something similar for CSS in a very simple manner by implementing `ICssSchemaFileProvider`.

From my research, there doesn't seem to be a simple way of doing this for HTML. Implementing an editor classifier seems to be the way to handle custom [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense), and it's fairly daunting vs the CSS provider that Mads implements.

I really just want to throw an XML schema into the classifier and have it complete HTML5 and my custom additions.

Is there a simple implementation of an editor classifier or some alternative approach?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Mads' post on implementing Angular IntelliSense](http://madskristensen.net/post/improved-javascript-intellisense-in-visual-studio), the HTML editor isn't extended in the same way. Instead, you would extend `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\html\commonHTML5Types.xsd`.

I think you could also create a new `exampleNameTypes.xsd` and reference it from `commonHTML5Types.xsd` using `<xsd:import schemaLocation="exampleNameTypes.xsd"/>` as they do for SVG.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jon, it's a shame there isn't a more native way to do this. Will explore further...

Comment: @craigomatic - did you ever find a solution to this? I'm trying to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: I don't have admin rights on my local machine and program files folders are locked down. I would expect there to be a way to add support for custom elements/attributes without needing to be a admin. #sadpanda PS. Still up-voted because it's a good answer.